# Keys & Values are not mapped correctly in jot specification

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

jolt Input:

```
{
    "Attachments": [{
        "AttachTime": "2022-05-20 12:00:37+00:00",
        "DeleteOnTermination": false
    }],
    "MultiAttachEnabled": false,
    "Size": 2990,
    "SnapshotId": "",
    "State": "in-use",
    "Tags": [{
            "Key": "BusinessUnit",
            "Value": "Platform"
        },
        {
            "Key": "DR",
            "Value": "Critical"
        },
        {
            "Key": "Env",
            "Value": "PRD"
        },
        {
            "Key": "Owner",
            "Value": "PLAT"
        }
    ],
    "Throughput": 12576
}
```

I have used below specification.

```
{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "Attachments": {
      "*": {
        "AttachTime": "AttachmentSet_Item_AttachTime",
        "DeleteOnTermination": "AttachmentSet_Item_DeleteOnTermination"
      }
    },
    "MultiAttachEnabled": "MultiAttachEnabled",
    "Size": "Size",
    "SnapshotId": "SnapshotId",
    "State": "State",
    "Tags": {
      "*": {
        "Key": "&1.TagSet_Item_Key",
        "Value": "&1.TagSet_Item_Value"
      }
    },
    "Throughput": "Throughput"
  }
}
```

Required Output is.

```
[{
        "TagSet_Item_Key": "BusinessUnit",
        "TagSet_Item_Value": "Platform",
        "AttachmentSet_Item_DeleteOnTermination": "false ",
        "State": "in-use ",
        "MultiAttachEnabled": " false",
        "AttachmentSet_Item_AttachTime": "2022-05-20 12:00:37+00:00",
        "Size": "2990 ",
        "SnapshotId": "",
        "Throughput": 12576
    },
    {
        
        "TagSet_Item_Key": "DR",
        "TagSet_Item_Value": "Critical",
        "AttachmentSet_Item_DeleteOnTermination": "false ",
        "State": "in-use ",
        "MultiAttachEnabled": " false",
        "AttachmentSet_Item_AttachTime": "2022-05-20 12:00:37+00:00",
        "Size": "2990 ",
        "Snapshotted": "",
        "Throughput": 12576
    }
]
```

expecting the output in this for:

```
[{
        "TagSet_Item_Key": "BusinessUnit",
        "TagSet_Item_Value": "Platform",
        "AttachmentSet_Item_DeleteOnTermination": "false ",
        "State": "in-use ",
        "MultiAttachEnabled": " false",
        "AttachmentSet_Item_AttachTime": "2022-05-20 12:00:37+00:00",
        "Size": "2990 ",
        "SnapshotId": "",
        "Throughput": 12576
    },
    {
        
        "TagSet_Item_Key": "DR",
        "TagSet_Item_Value": "Critical",
        "AttachmentSet_Item_DeleteOnTermination": "false ",
        "State": "in-use ",
        "MultiAttachEnabled": " false",
        "AttachmentSet_Item_AttachTime": "2022-05-20 12:00:37+00:00",
        "Size": "2990 ",
        "SnapshotId": "",
        "Throughput": 12576
    }
]
```

I have tried as
[

{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
"Attachments": {
"*": {
"AttachTime": "AttachmentSet_Item_AttachTime",
"DeleteOnTermination": "AttachmentSet_Item_DeleteOnTermination",
}
},
"AvailabilityZone": "AvailabilityZone",
"CreateTime": "CreateTime",
"Encrypted": "Encrypted",

```
  "MultiAttachEnabled": "MultiAttachEnabled",
  "Size": "Size",
  "SnapshotId": "SnapshotId",
  "State": "State",
  "Tags": {
    "*": {
      "Key": "&1.TagSet_Item_Key",
      "Value": "&1.TagSet_Item_Value"
    }
  },
  "Throughput": "Throughput"
}
```

}
]

Comment: Hi. Have you ever possibly duplicated the `Input` and `Required Output` ..?